# compare column of two rows of same table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table name `player_history` containing history of player. in this table having column player_id, Final_position,meeting_code,race_no and beaten_time. If a player stood a first or second position the time will be same there are meeting code one day and in each meeting code there are maximum 10 races.

I want to select those records where 1st and second position beaten time are not same.

```
player_id Meeting_Code race_no final_position beaten_time
  1         0001          1         1             2
  2         0001          1         2             2
  1         0001          2         1             5
  2         0001          2         2             6        
... so on
```

Output should be:

```
player_id Meeting_Code race_no final_position beaten_time
  1         0001          2         1             5
  2         0001          2         2             6
```

Also if it is not correct I want to update records of first position only.

Answer (score 0):

Let table name be `Test`. Try to put Self Join or something like this:

```
Select t1.player_id t1.Meeting_Code t1.race_no t1.final_position t1.beaten_time
From Test t1
LEFT JOIN Test t2 ON t1.beaten_time != t2.beaten_time.
```

Try like this. It might work.

Comment: thanks for your answer but the table has other positions as well up 20 i only want to check on position 1 and 2. I want same time that is on position 2 will be on position 1.

Comment: In that case add extra where condition with t1.final_position IN(1,2). try this with the above query and check it please.

Comment: It is not working . Is this possible with out selecting data i can update all 1st position time with second.
What ever value in 1st position will be replaced by the value of second position having same meeting code and race_no

Comment: well i am not sure how to achieve that.  But what did you get after appending "Where t1.final_position IN(1,2) " with above query?

Comment: It is giving wrong data ok no problem i will write small function for this

Answer (score 0):

Check this it will work

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY player_id
HAVING count(beaten_time) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try It:

```
select b.player_id,b.meeting_code,b.race_no,b.final_position,b.beaten_time 
from player_history a,player_history b
where  a.race_no = b.race_no and a.beaten_time != b.beaten_time;
```